# Is there an Oracle equivalent for the T-SQL PRINT statement? I want to show script progress

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have searched and not found any answers that address this directly.  I just want to display that I have successfully completed script blocks while executing an implementation script that does multiple things.

```
PRINT 'Start script'
PRINT 'Insert A'
    INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
    VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Stavanger', 'Norway');
PRINT 'Update B'
    UPDATE Customers
    SET ContactName='Alfred Schmidt', City='Hamburg'
    WHERE CustomerName='Alfreds Futterkiste';
PRINT 'End script'
```

So, when done, the output should look something like:

```
Start script
Insert A
4 rows inserted
Update B
1 row updated
End script
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has a database output buffer called `DBMS Output`, which has a `PUT_LINE()` function. However, most Oracle tools (`SQL*Plus` and `SQL Developer`) do not have the output buffer enabled, by default, in a session.

To turn on this output buffer in `SQL Developer`, do the following:

1. Go to `View` | `DBMS Output` to enable the DBMS Output window
2. Push the green plus icon to enable DBMS Output for a particular session.

To turn on this output buffer on in `SQL*Plus!`, you need to set the `SERVEROUTPUT` value via the command prompt, like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON [SIZE N|UNLIMITED]
```

Example:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 50000
```

> Note: The `50000` is a length limit, in bytes.

---

Now you can use the `PUT_LINE()` function to actually write status messages, like this:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Status message goes here.');
```

---

Here is the documentation for [SET SERVEROUTPUT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699298) PL-SQL command.

Here is the documentation for [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_output.html) function.

Answer (score 2):

For SQLPlus, there is the PROMPT command.

Syntax:

```
PRO[MPT] [text]
```

> where text represents the text of the message you want to display.
>
> Sends the specified message or a blank line to the user's screen. If you omit text, PROMPT displays a blank line on the user's screen.

---

Usage:

> You can use this command in scripts to give information to the user.

---

Examples:

> The following example shows the use of `PROMPT` in conjunction with `ACCEPT` in a script called `ASKFORDEPT.SQL`. `ASKFORDEPT.SQL` contains the following `SQL*Plus` and `SQL` commands:

```
PROMPT
PROMPT Please enter a valid department
PROMPT For example:  10
SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEWWHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = &NEWDEPT
```

> Assume you run the file using START or @:

```
@ASKFORDEPT.SQL VAL1
@HTTP://machine_name.domain:port/ASKFORDEPT.SQL VAL1
```

---

```
Please enter a valid department
For example: 10
Department ID?>
```

You can enter a department number at the prompt `Department ID?>`. By default, SQL*Plus lists the line containing `&NEWDEPT` before and after substitution, and then displays the department name corresponding to the number entered at the `Department ID?>` prompt. You can use SET VERIFY OFF to prevent this behaviour.

---

Read full documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/toc.htm).

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to prompt the user.  I just want the message interlaced with the actual output.  Also, I tried PROMPT and it does not work with multiple executions of commends in a single script.